# Joomla 4 Security: Is it worth tracking attacks for the Joomla team?

Tags: joomla-4.x, security, hack

Shortly after I (finally) managed to upgrade to Joomla 4 my development site was taken down by an attack.  (I dont' know how exactly yet).

Is it worth my time to work out how this happened?  How would I report this to the Joomla Team if it wasn't a simple misconfiguration that allowed the attack to take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's also worth the time for your own benefit:

- was it some server software vulnerability
- was it a local computer vulnerability that was used to gain access to the (s)FTP credentials of your website
- was it a 3rd party extension vulnerability
- or was it an unknown Joomla 4.x vulnerability

You can use that info to make sure that this hack does not happen again.

### Other things to consider

- Did you obtain all software (Joomla + extension) from reliable sources? If it was a 3rd party vulnerability: please contact the developers so that they can take action regarding their extension
- Did you consult your hosting company? If it was a server issue then other users on the same shared hosting server might have been compromised too.

### To investigate the issue

- Create a backup of the hacked site (for later analysis) and store at your local computer
- Copy the server access and error log files asap to your local computer. Most servers use log rotate and only keep the log files for 7 days or so.

### Joomla! Security Strike Team

In case you find an unknown **vulnerability in Joomla 4.x**, please **contact** the **Joomla! Security Strike Team** in private so that a security fix can be developed and released: https://developer.joomla.org/security.html

Comment: Thanks, after hours going through the access logs... It's not hacked. Joomla 4 has slowed up my server so that the requests were being served slowly. My load balancer thought that the server was down because requests took longer than 5s to return 200 http responses

Comment: There's an issue with Joomla! 4.2.1 slow page load, see: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=817&t=996159
It's caused by the "System - WebAuthn Passwordless Login" Plugin. You can solve it by disabling that plugin. And there's already a PR available: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/38664